# Alter column default value is not working in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I tried to update column's default value with the below queries in postgres. But seems its not working. May be I am missing something. Could you help?

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN newColumn INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

 ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN newColumn DROP DEFAULT;
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN newColumn SET DEFAULT NULL;

 SELECT * FROM tableName;
```

Here I still find 0.

Comment: The (new) default value will only be applied when you insert new rows. It does not change anything for the existing rows

Answer (score 1):

The change only applies to new records. After the modification you have to heal all the previous data with a migration like this:

```
UPDATE tableName SET newColumn = NULL WHERE newColumn = 0
```